# Handling datetime in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm dealing with a dataset that has a column called "start_date". The data type of this column is an object.

The "start_date" column has some values like:

```
26/07/2020  9:00:00 AM
25/07/2020  11:06:00 AM
05/09/2020  6:11:00 PM
06/08/2020  1:36:00 AM
```

I need to extract the month and day for each row. To do this I used this:

```
df['Day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['start_date']).day
df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['start_date']).month
```

The output should be something like this:

```
Day   Month
26     7
25     7
5      9
6      8
```

But it gave me this:

```
Day   Month
26     7
25     7
9      5
8      6
```

The problem is that, in the 3rd row, the day should be 5 and the month is 9. But it read it in the opposite way.

Similarly, in the 4th row, the day should be 6 and the month is 8. But it read it in the opposite way.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dayfirst=True`

With [`pandas.DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html):

```
df['Day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['start_date'], dayfirst=True).day
df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['start_date'], dayfirst=True).month
```

or, with [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], dayfirst=True).dt.day
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'], dayfirst=True).dt.month
```

output:

```
                start_date  Day  Month
0   26/07/2020  9:00:00 AM   26      7
1  25/07/2020  11:06:00 AM   25      7
2   05/09/2020  6:11:00 PM    5      9
3   06/08/2020  1:36:00 AM    6      8
```

documentation:

> dayfirstbool, default False
>
> Specify a date parse order if arg is str or is list-like. If True, parses dates with the day first, e.g. "10/11/12" is parsed as
> 2012-11-10.
>
> **Warning**
>
> dayfirst=True is not strict, but will prefer to parse with day first. If a delimited date string cannot be parsed in accordance with
> the given dayfirst option, e.g. to_datetime(['31-12-2021']), then a
> warning will be shown.